# UWP App: Process Memory Usage vs Heap Usage

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to profile my UWP (Universal Windows Platform) app in Visual Studio to see what is causing my Process Memory Usage to be so high.

I've been using Visual Studio's built in Diagnostic Tools and I haven't had any luck.
It's been showing my Process Memory Usage at 93 megabytes while the Heap shows 12.17 MB and the Managed Heap shows 1.56 MB.

[image]

There was just another instance where my Process Memory Usage ran up to about 458 MB and kept climbing, but when I took a snapshot, it didn't tell me the values of any of the objects that should of been causing it, and the actual memory it claimed to be using was so much less than the Process Memory.

[image]

I'm not sure if I just don't understand how the profiler works, or I'm just doing something completely wrong entirely.

Comment: The managed heap reserves lots of memory up front, without actually using it. The figures you get for *Managed Heap* is the amount of used managed heap. The unused managed heap still contributes to your application's memory usage. When writing code in an unmanaged language, the figures will be less confusing.

Comment: @IInspectable that makes a lot of sense, but why would it allocate so much more memory than needed? There's other instances where my Process Memory Usage will be around 700 MB while my managed heap is still only around 50 MBs

Comment: @IInspectable I just added another picture with a few more snapshots trying to explain my problem.

Comment: That's just how the CLR's managed heap is implemented: It uses memory quite aggressively, and keeps objects on the managed heap often significantly longer than needed. Once reserved memory is committed by the managed heap, it will count towards the process' private bytes. Memory is only ever uncommitted during a Gen 2 GC, and since that's pretty costly it only runs, when memory pressure gets high. A very in-depth look at the managed heap is available at [Advanced .NET Debugging: Managed Heap and Garbage Collection](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1409801).

Comment: Is there a way to throw away the objects being retained then? When I called GC.Collect() it doesn't make a difference

Comment: Calling [GC.Collect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx) will not compact the large object heap (LOH). Even if Gen 2 objects were garbage collected, the managed heap may not be able to uncommit memory. You'd have to explicitly ask for the LOH to be compacted, by setting the [GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property to `CompactOnce`. If this doesn't change memory usage, then your observations may be the result of something else.

Comment: That didn't seem to fix it; I'm trying to look into other options. I have noticed in the DiagnosticTools it shows that GC was called but I can't figure out where or why. I'm sorry for seeming very ignorant about this. I never learned much about optimizing the memory usage.

Comment: Do you have a reason to optimize memory usage at all? The graphs don't indicate, that memory usage continuously grows, so this may just be the amount of memory your application needs. If you still feel that you are using more memory than necessary there's at least one common mistake that you can investigate: Creating circular references, that keep objects from being garbage collected. This happens for example, when you capture a *this* reference in a lambda expression and assign it to an event handler.

Comment: With a few sections of the app it does continuously grow, but I'd also prefer it to not be using that much memory when its just sitting still.

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is - even though your app is written in C# - it still allocates large amounts of native memory.

Typically bitmaps you load in an app use most memory, so I would start looking into reducing the number and resolution of bitmaps you have in your memory and making sure they don't leak.

Second - make sure your lists are virtualized. If you load 1000 images in memory - even if they are small they will still use a lot of memory. By default - list controls like `ListBox`, `ListView` or `GridView` are virtualized, unless you put them in a `ScrollViewer` or change the default `ItemsPanel` to one that isn't virtualized.

Comment: I'll definitely look into this.
I have noticed that just the basic app with nothing in it uses 40 MBs, that's not bad but it's also not the best.